# How to move includegraphics to the next line

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, lists

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{wedge.eps}
    \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

I would like image to be below item number, namely on the next line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but the image is in its own line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \mbox{}

    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics*[height=5cm]{example-image}
    \end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why does this work here?

Comment: @Yola The empty line means a linebreak, but to be able to break a line there has to be some text on the previous line. `\mbox{}` is the most harmless text I could think of, but you can replace it by something else if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
  \item \mbox{}
```

so the `center` enviornment comes underneath a blank line, or probably better use `adjustbox` package to add vertical align keys to `\includegraphics` and add  `[valign=t]` so it aligns on the top not the bottom.